# Is there are TwiML Request Paramter for Message Time/Date

Tags: twilio-php, twilio-twiml

According to the docs, when Twilio receives a message from a Twilio numbers it makes a synchronous HTTP request to the message URL configured for that number. Twilio sends the the parameters listed at https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request

Is it possible to have the date/time sent and/or received passed to the configured URL as well, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Dates and Times are [addressed as such](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request#dates-and-times) and are attached to the [messages resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message#instance-properties).

```
{
   "account_sid": "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
   "api_version": "2010-04-01",
   "body": "Hey test message",
   "error_code": null,
   "error_message": null,
   "num_segments": "1",
   "num_media": "0",
   "date_created": "Mon, 16 Aug 2010 03:45:01 +0000",
   "date_sent": "Mon, 16 Aug 2010 03:45:03 +0000",
   "date_updated": "Mon, 16 Aug 2010 03:45:03 +0000",
   "direction": "outbound-api",
   "from": "+14158141829",
   "price": "-0.02000",
   "sid": "MMXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
   "status": "sent",
   "to": "+15558675309",
   "uri": "/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Messages/MMXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXec.json"
}
```